# Security/Connection Issue with Selenium Webdriver in Python [WinError 10061]

Tags: python, selenium

I'm building a crawler and finding a strange issue with when I try to use a get command:

```
drive.get("http://google.com")
```

This will throw the error:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it

However, if I manually type in and visit a webpage in the browser instance created and re-run the command above, I no longer receive the error and I am able to proceed with testing.

Prior to entering the web address, my browser shows 'not secure' however after I enter, it changes to secure.

Before:

https://puu.sh/w3qI2/93da033591.png

After:

https://puu.sh/w3qxa/27616622e9.png

So, as long as I pause the code when the browser opens and visit a webpage, my get command works, otherwise I receive the error shown above.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver = r"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Crawler\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
#pause here and enter any web address into browser
drive.get("http://google.com")
```

Does anyone know how I can set the security of the browser to always be 'secure' when it is opened by selenium?

Comment: You see "Secure" when you visit site by secured protocol (`https`) and "Not secure" if visit by insecure (`http`)- it's not related to `Selenium`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any major issue in your code. Having said that, as you have initialized the webdriver instance as `driver`, you may consider using the same `driver` to open the url "http://google.com". So your code block may look as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver = r"C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
#pause here and enter any web address into browser
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I discovered the issue, it turns out that the problem arose when I closed the browser and tried to run a driver.get command. The solution is to re-open the browser using the webdriver.Chrome command then all other commands that follow will execute without a problem.